# What is the probability of picking $k=3$ red balls among $n=5$ red or blue balls.

Tags: probability

We blindly pick a ball from a pool that has infinite number of balls. The colour of a ball could be red or blue. The probability to pick a red and blue ball is 0.8 and 0.2, respectively.

After 5 times picking, what's the probability that we have picked exactly 3 red balls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is
$${5\choose 3}0.8^3 0.2^{5-3}$$
because there are ${5\choose 3}$ possible equally likely ways to pick exactly three red balls, each of them being equally as likely as the sequence (red, red, red, blue, blue), which has probability $0.8\cdot 0.8\cdot0.8\cdot0.2\cdot0.2$.

Comment: It should be mentionned that the underlying distribution is a binomial law $B(5,0.8)$.